# how to load two tables data into single table side by side

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have two table and I want only two columns from each table.
    and I want to keep these total four columns into one table.

Example:-

S1, S2, S3 Columns of Table1
S4, S5, S6 Columns of Table2

And I want the columns S1, S2, S4, S5 in my Table-3.

Can any one solve this in hive.

Comment: are the two tables in Mysql? and you want the new table in hive?

Comment: Is there a common link between the two tables??

Answer (score 0):

If there is any column in Table1 and Table2 that can be used for join just use:

```
select t1.S1, t1.S2, t2.S4, t2.S5 
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2 
where t1.column_for_join = t2.column_for_join
```

And the result will be `Table3 (S1,S2,S4,S5)`

If there is no column for join, you can use union like this:

```
select S1,S2, null, null from Table1
union
select null, null, S4,S5 from Table2
```

Hope is helps...
Pawel